# Как сделать узкоспециализированный сайт интересным для пользователей?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

Как известно, в наше время SEO теряет свою значимость, т.к. поисковики прежде всего обращают внимание на поведенческие факторы: количество уникальных посетителей, время их нахождения на сайте, повторное посещение итд.

Передо мной стоит задача раскрутить сайт, посвященный продаже дробильно-сортировочного оборудования. Я не шарю в этой теме, да и в теме раскрутки в частности. Мне интересны только разработка и программирование. Отказаться от проекта не могу по семейным обстоятельствам)

Что мне можете посоветовать в этом случае, как повысить позиции сайта в поисковой выдаче? Накидайте идеи пожалуйста

Comment: > Как сделать сайт, посвященный продаже дробильно-сортировочного оборудования, интересным для пользователей?

Никак?

Comment: ну разве что казуалками на дробильно строительную тему. помню была в детстве игрушка диггер. 
![DIGGER](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Digger.JPG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно понять, кто является вашим пользователем. Это далеко не обычный юзер, а специалист, развитый в этой области. А обычно эти люди не сильно продвинуты в сайтах, так что делать "что-то прикольное" нет смысла. Главное верно описать товар.
Основная проблема в том, что сайт действительно узкоспециализированный. И нет необходимости его раскручивать для всех, ведь никто просто не возьмет и не будет сидеть на этом сайте (это магазин, а не соц сеть), так что Вам достаточно в различныех источниках накидать ссылок на данный сайт, чтобы его можно было легко найти в поисковых системах, и обязательно написать уникальный контент, который будет отличать сайт от массы похожих.

Answer (score -1):

Да все просто по сути:

1. Берешь свой главный запрос - "дробильно-сортировочное оборудование".
2. Втыкаешь его [сюда](https://wordstat.yandex.ru/), затем парсишь левую колонку - все слова что выдаст + так же смотришь в правую, ишешь похожие и похожие тоже парсишь аналогичным образом.
3. Как собрал все запросы - формируешь их по страницам. То есть нам надо что бы любой запрос на странице четко предоставлял раскрытую информацию без воды. И не забываем про структуру сайта.
4. Затем делаем оптимизацию страниц - title, описания, ключи, h1, h2, картинки и так далее. Потом каталоги, форумы по теме (это самый минимум).

Ну и много можно рассказывать. Советую обратиться в контору за продвижением сайта, например [эту](http://www.top-7.ru). Успехов!

Answer (score -1):

Ну очевидно же: сделать сайт с интересным и актуальным материалом для целевой аудитории. Все. Точка.